# Down-vote inspection per request

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderation, reporting

Just a feature request, most likely will be bashed down, but whatever, I will pour out what I have on my mind, which I think would address something.

There should be a way to report/flag ridiculous vote-casts. Reporting ability can get moderated, may get revoked after a specific number of false conducts occur, for example 3. Valid reports are to bring about actions against the voting ability of the ridiculous-voter. Yeah, I'm not much into democracy.

Of course, I have brought this to here after something, and here's that something: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701051/2736228 - an answer that I have just written

Examine it as you please, I would be more than happy to hear any sensible reason for that answer to get voted down. I honestly enjoy helping others on things that I can. I really get some sort of fake-satisfaction out of this.

There shouldn't be anything to vote down there, if not to vote up. Let me tell you why it most likely got voted down: The reason is that I have voted down another answer, and have given the reason why it just absolutely deserves a vote-down right beneath. That answer with my comment beneath can be found there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701071/2736228

Now what? I don't really care, truly, I helped that guy over there, he said that I was helpful, and that was all that I've wanted. I don't really care about the points, vote-ups or downs. I do care about the tick-mark, because it is a mark of having been helpful. I got what I want.

Right now, I want to help, help the community, help the rest, again. Whoever, most likely that guy, is the one who voted the answer I gave down, is most likely providing misconduct all around. There are people out there examining the flagged posts/questions. There could be more people to check such suspects.

Not that I cannot ever give an answer that would deserve a down-vote, don't take me as a megalomaniac; it's just about that specific answer I gave.

Comment: IMO, weird voting patterns are detected by the system and moderator can check them out...

Comment: What do you want to be able to report and what do you expect moderators to do?  Voting is an individual's choice and earned privileges.  My vote shouldn't be invalidated just because someone else disagreed with it.

Comment: I haven't looked up voting details for your answer (and if I had, I wouldn't be at liberty to reveal who voted on it in any case), but are you seriously implying that "This is not an answer, more like a "GT*O" or something..." is a good comment? I suggest you don't bother leaving comments if that's your idea of explaining your reasoning. [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @psubsee2003 Not just your vote, but your voting ability altogether should be put under inspection, and invalidated if required. It would be equivalent to saying "Okay, it was a mistake to give you this privilege.". People take what they gave back when they realize that it was a mistake, even more so when it was given automatically.

Comment: Compare your comment with [the one left by Adam Zuckerman](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700677/c-how-to-use-leftmost-digit-from-a-interger/22701071#comment34590543_22701165) on another answer: "A more detailed explanation of your answer would be helpful. Newer developers will not necessarily understand the concepts you are trying to convey."

Comment: @ThoAppelsin someone who is actively downvoting your posts because they disagree with you personally is one thing.  That is called serial voting and that is against the rules, but beyond that, a single downvote is a single downvote.  Someone may simply have disagreed with your solution.  Why should their vote be disallowed because a 3rd person (moderator or not) disagrees with the vote.

Comment: @AnnaLear Anna, I had seen that comment, it indeed is obviously more mannered, but the answer under which he commented is also less brutal. It only assumes that the one who asked the question knows about what logarithm is, it even shows some kind of effort in giving a nice answer with non-code texts around. On the other hand, the answer under which I've commented looks exactly the way I described with my comment; with that recursion out of the blue with not a single line of explanation anywhere. It is like saying "Take this code and leave me alone, this is not a place for you."

Comment: Meh. Everyone gets some unfair downvotes from time to time. They are incredibly irritating but they are usually drowned out by upvotes.

Comment: @Pëkka And I am only suggesting something to get rid of that irritating thing, since in most cases it would be easy to detect.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin How on earth is the system going to detect my motivation for voting something down (or up, for that matter)?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin I'm in no way defending that answer. It would greatly benefit from an explanation to go along with that code. My point still stands, however.

Comment: @AnnaLear Adam (idealizing that guy as a perfection for now, I don't know about him) wouldn't leave such a nice comment underneath the answer which I've commented. He would either leave down a harsh and bitter one, or wouldn't leave any at all.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Honestly, leaving no comment at all is an improvement over the one you left.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin So now you know exactly how other people will behave? What kind of psychic are you? Please don't state what other people may or may not do when you can't possibly know that's what they will do. This is getting rather silly.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It got silly when my comment to a question got compared with another comment to another question. Cases were not analogous, all that was left to me was to predict. One another silly thing is your ridiculous comment, what the hell...

Comment: If it makes you feel better: I also have [an accepted answer with -1 rating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836733/change-the-button-style-when-cliqued-android/21836902#21836902). I actually think it is a kind of a cool thing. There maybe should be a badge for that :-D

Comment: @donfuxx It did, kind of, thanks for sharing that :D

Comment: I knew it!!!  Lol!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Disclaimer: this answer is meant to be taken as general commentary, not necessarily as a response to your specific example.)

We detect and handle [serial voting patterns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), both for upvotes and downvotes. There's also some work in the pipeline to improve the tools available to moderators while still keeping individual votes anonymous. We do not, however, police individual votes and judge their validity.

I've done a lot of vote analysis over my time as a moderator and employee, and there are two things that stand out to me from that experience:

1. Fraudulent votes are usually very obvious; and
2. In the vast majority of cases folks are dead wrong when they make assumptions about who voted on their posts and why.

Opening up a way for everyone to hyper-focus on individual votes is a sure path to madness, and no good can come of it.

Comment: Well, that's an answer.

Answer (score 14):

> I would be more than happy to hear any sensible reason for that answer to get voted down.

Here's the thing: we are allowed to down-vote for whatever reason we feel like, sensible or not. There are literally unlimited reasons why someone might have down-voted an answer (including the incredible possibility that there is something wrong with it). Only the down-voter could comment why. Speculating who it was and assuming it must have been revenge and not for a legitimate reason is silly and pointless - even if they tell you they down-voted, or explained a problem with the post, there is still no guarantee it was actually them who down-voted. I don't know C, so I couldn't be bothered to try and guess what could be wrong, but have you entertained the notion that something is wrong? Have you considered that someone could down-vote for a reason as silly as not liking horizontal scrollbars?

Which brings us to the next point about explaining down-votes. [This is just not going to happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), as there is no way to force people to leave useful, constructive comments about why they down-voted. They'll either stop doing it altogether (not good), or leave gibberish (also not good).

Comment: I seriously do not want to read this text which starts off with "We may do what we want, because we can, because we have been entitled to", but I will; maybe I can see why this has been voted up 3 times by far.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Note that I am not advocating that people *should* down-vote for any reason they feel like, just that they *can*. I am also trying to strike a chord with you that, just maybe, someone sees a problem in your answer that you, yourself, don't see.

Comment: Why should anyone who is voting down answers for having horizontal scrollbars in it, should keep his/her privilege to vote down even? It is just a privilege that people gain for doing nothing much really, just 125 reputation which really proves nothing. On the other hand, if it can be shown that someone voted for no sensible reason, that would prove that that someone shouldn't really have that privilege.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Because there is no subjective way to magically interpret exactly why someone down-voted. I could only up-vote answers posted by users who have Beaker as their avatar, and only down-vote answers posted by users who have Muppet avatars other than Beaker. How is the system going to know? How do you propose that it be shown that someone voted for no sensible reason, unless they say something like "I didn't down-vote this for a good reason, but rather because you're a jerk"? Even then, how can you *prove* they are the one who down-voted?

Comment: (okay, the chat is getting mixed, this refers to the 2nd comment here, your first) And in that case I could be informed about the thing I have done wrong, the thing that I cannot see. Until then, I should be able to ask for an inspection, maybe after 250 reputations, maybe 300, on my down-vote. If someone else (a moderator in this case) also cannot see what could possibly be wrong with my answer, then maybe something is rather wrong with the down-voter?

Comment: There is a reason people don't comment when they down-vote: vengeful behavior. I tell you what's wrong with your answer, and you disagree, and feel slighted, and tomorrow you down-vote two of my posts, three the next day, two next Wednesday, etc. to "get back at me." Since the down-voter can't be forced to inform you, I still don't understand how the system is going to magically guess that the down-vote was deserved or not. Also, I can hardly be considered evidence that I found nothing wrong in your answer: I can barely spell C. I think you need to just let it go; the system is not changing.

Comment: "How?", by having it checked by someone else, extremely critically, see if there could be anything, any bit of sensible thing that could really be the reason why it could have got down-voted. This is not un-doable as you project.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Who exactly is this critical all-knowing person?

Comment: Whoever that are currently closing questions? Dude, I really cannot understand why you're making it look so impossible. There already are subjective mechanisms going all around. I have flagged a lot of things, many of them got approved and actions were taken for them, some of them were declined and found not useful. Were the ones who had done all that *"critical all-knowing" people*? Please, let's not say things to each other just to oppose each other...

Comment: @Tho /sigh /unsubscribe

Comment: Top kek. Lel, wow, writing nonsense, getting a vote up. Who's doing all that really? This place truly is insane, compared to Stack Overflow.